# a diophantine equation from Stewart and Tall

Tags: number-theory

This is from Stewart and Tall from the chapter on Kummer's Theorem. Show that there are no non trivial  (non-zero) solutions to
$x^3 + y^3=3z^3$

Comment: Have you tried reduction modulo a prime?